# Horrible VMware keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, vmware, shortcut

I'm a VMware user and far too often I use keyboard shortcuts while programming. However, this has proved to be quite distressing as sometimes the VMware gets hold of it and turns off / pauses (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) the virtual machine.

Is there a way to disable keyboard shortcuts on VMware? Has anyone here ever found a workaround?

Comment: Yes!  Although not programming-related, this is probably the most annoying keyboard shortcut I've ever encountered.

Comment: Please reopen this question. VMWare and other virtual environments are becoming much more common for both development and production and are as relevant as the "Best programming mouse" and other environmental questions.

Comment: I totally agree with Rob Allen.

Comment: This shouldn't have been closed... I reopened.

Comment: My favorite is Ctrl-E.  Shuts down the vm, no questions asked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use AutoHotKey (are you running VMWare on Windows ?) to disable certain shortcuts. You can find this tool here:

http://www.autohotkey.com/

It's open source and I quite like it. Can be used for automation tasks, but you can also have it respond differently to different windows. With some AHK scripting, I think you should be able to fix your problem.

The site had got loads of tutorials too on writing handy scripts.

Good luck.

Comment: Maybe you can share your configuration with us?

Answer (score 4):

If it is Ok for you - here's a bit of hacky solution which is very simple - just use ResHacker program to get rid of those annoying accelerators (they are defined as resources in vmware.exe).

Comment: +1 It's a hack, but it works!

Comment: Thanks very much for the straightforward solution! For anyone else attempting this, the shortcuts are in the "Accelerators" tab. Just find the lines relative to VK_R, VK_E, VK_J (or the concerning hot keys), remove them, compile the script and save the new executable.

Answer (score 2):

This was very annoying to me as well. I finally resolved it for me by doing the following:

1. Open the VMWare Workstation preferences (Edit menu | Preferences)
2. Select the Input tab
3. Check the "Grab keyboard and mouse input on key press" option.

This way, if your mouse drifts outside the virtual machine's window, when you type someting, the virtual machine will "regain" focus.